# Incrementing statements to track comparisons in recursive method

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, increment, binary-search

I am trying to construct a recursive binary search  method that searches a sorted array of comparable objects for an object of interest. This is part of a larger algorithm that searches a collection of sorted arrays and looks for elements common to all arrays in the collection. The goal is to make the search/comparison portion of the algorithm as efficient as possible. A linear solution should be possible. This is the method:

```
private static boolean BinarySearch(Comparable[] ToSearch, Comparable ToFind, int first, int last){
    boolean found = false;
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    comparisons++;
    if(first > last){
        found = false;
    }
    else if(ToFind.compareTo(ToSearch[mid]) == 0){
        found = true;
        comparisons++;
    }
    else if(ToFind.compareTo(ToSearch[mid]) < 0) {
        found = BinarySearch(ToSearch, ToFind, first, mid - 1);
        comparisons++;
    }
    else{
        found = BinarySearch(ToSearch, ToFind,mid + 1, last);
        comparisons++;
    }
    return found;
}
```

The problem I am having is tracking the number of comparisons through the recursion. Because I have to count the comparisons that evaluate to false as well as true, I tried to placing the comparison incrementing statement inside each selection statement but this does not work because the statement is not incremented if the statement evaluates to false. I also cannot place them between the selection statements because that would give me else without if erros. I am wondering if it was a bad idea to use recursion at all for the search but I want to believe it is possible. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you could set a variable in each `if` block with the number of comparisons it took to get there, and add it at the end?

```
private static boolean BinarySearch(Comparable[] ToSearch, Comparable ToFind, int first, int last){
    boolean found = false;
    int newComparisons = 0;
    int mid = first + (last - first) / 2;
    if(first > last){
        found = false;
        newComparisons = 1;
    }
    else if(ToFind.compareTo(ToSearch[mid]) == 0){
        found = true;
        newComparisons = 2;
    }
    else if(ToFind.compareTo(ToSearch[mid]) < 0) {
        found = BinarySearch(ToSearch, ToFind, first, mid - 1);
        newComparisons = 3;
    }
    else{
        found = BinarySearch(ToSearch, ToFind,mid + 1, last);
        newComparisons = 3;
    }
    comparisons += newComparisons;
    return found;
}
```

Comment: You could just do the increment directly, e.g. `comparisons += 3;` in the `else`, but up-vote from me.

Comment: Thats not a bad idea. Though I would use Andreas'  statement:  comparisons +=3 because of another method in my class that returns the value of comparisons to track efficiency based on number of entries in Query array. I will give this a try.